# Hiding Facebook "Comment activity" and "Friending activity" prevents status updates from showing up on my own wall

Tags: facebook

On Facebook, since I selected "Comment activity" and "Friending activity" as my "Hidden story types", whenever I post a link or a status on my own wall, it disappears from my wall and is only visible in the news feed.

I know my friends can see what I post on their news feed but not when they check my wall.

Is it a bug?
If it is intended, how to have my wall display my links and status updates, while hiding "Comment activity" and "Friending activity"?

Comment: It sounds like you are confused about what the wall, your recent activity, your news feed and your friends' news feeds are about and how they are related to what you are actually hiding. Please post a screenshot (with sensitive info blurred) to show the steps to reproduce what you are talking about.

Comment: From privacy settings, you can hide the wall from all or from specific people, is that you want

Comment: @phwd: I will try to explain better and detail the steps

Comment: @crucified: No, that's not what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

same thing happened to me. this helps though:

http://www.readactor.com/articles/how-to-hide-all-friending-activity-on-facebook/

> On the Facebook wall,on the right hand of your recent activity you’ll find a button from where you get two options, to remove the post (nothing new) and “hide all friending activity” A popup window needs your confirmation. Also there you have a link to your profile story settings manager. You can access at any time this settings.
>
> [image]
>
> Same thing and with the “like” notifier. You can now hide all “like” activity. Actually, you have now a more flexibility in set the privacy options for almost all things what are posted on your Facebook wall. Test this settings yourself!
>
> [image]
>
> The profile story settings manager unfortunately is not easy to be find. You can spend time to take a look in any profile or account setting but you never find it. The link for this settings is placed at very bottom of your Facebook wall. Scroll down your wall, wait to load stories, scroll again and there you will find the link pointed in the previous screenshot.
>
> [image]

Comment: The website is down. What did it say? Can you quote the most vital part from there? This answer is useless otherwise.

Comment: @eight so naggy!